# Adding new polygon attribute column based on location withing another polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, sf, sp

I have here an example with two layers - one containing two large polygons `Pol_large`, and second containing 4 small polygons `Pol_small`. For `Pol_small`
I want now to find the location of each of the small polygons within the large polygons creating a new attribute column `location` and transporting the attributes from the `Pol_large$id` column. It would look following:

```
Pol_small$location
[1] "A1" "A1" "A2" "A2"
```

Not sure which funciton in `sf` or `sp` would be best to do it.

```
library(sp)

create_poly <- function(coordin,id_number){
  coordinates = matrix(c(coordin[1], coordin[3],
                         coordin[1], coordin[4],
                         coordin[2], coordin[4],
                         coordin[2], coordin[3],
                         coordin[1], coordin[3]), 
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  P_1 = Polygon(coordinates)
  Ps_1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P_1), ID = id_number)), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
  ID_1 <- sapply(slot(Ps_1, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
  df <- data.frame(rep(0, length(ID_1)), row.names=ID_1)
  Ps1_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Ps_1, df)
  Ps1_df
}

# Create shapefile with polygon boundaries of interest:
Pol_1 <- create_poly(c(50,100,10,50),1)
Pol_2 <- create_poly(c(110,170,0,50),1)
Pol_3 <- create_poly(c(55,65,40,45),1)
Pol_4 <- create_poly(c(70,90,30,50),1)
Pol_5 <- create_poly(c(145,160,20,40),1)
Pol_6 <- create_poly(c(120,135,10,30),1)

# Join the polygons into one layer and assign attributes:
Pol_large <- do.call(rbind, list(Pol_1, Pol_2))
Pol_large$id <- c("A1","A2")
Pol_small <- do.call(rbind, list(Pol_3, Pol_4, Pol_5, Pol_6))
Pol_small$id <- c("b1","b2","b3","b4")

# Plot
plot(Pol_large, axes = TRUE)
plot(Pol_small, add=T, col = "blue")
```

Is this solution optimal? For some reason, in my real large example, this does not seem to work exactly as it should - specifically some smaller polygons with boundaries touching the edges of the large polygons do not get any assignment, they return `integer(0)`

```
library(sf)    
a <- unlist(st_within(st_as_sf(Pol_small),st_as_sf(Pol_large)))

for (i in 1:length(a)){
  g <- a[i]
  Pol_small$location[i] <- Pol_large$id[g]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found a solution which solves my large dataset problem using:
`library(lwgeom)
a <- st_is_within_distance(st_as_sf(Pol_small),st_as_sf(Pol_large),1)`
Not ideal but does the job now (luckily the large polygons have large spacing between each other

Comment: The `st_is_within_distance` function does not come from `lwgom` it is in the `sf`package and likely originates in GEOS.

Comment: What do you mean by 'location within'? Does the larger polygon need to entirely contain the smaller polygon? Do they merely need to intersect? Are you interested in intersections where only the edge overlaps?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually: Iterate over each large polygon, using intersect to determine which small polygons intersect it. Then, using the centroid of each small polygon as it's 'location', calculate the distance and bearing of each small polygon to that large polygon. The data will be assigned to each small polygon.